# How to play .avi file in Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, video-processing, opencv3.0

I have found only ways to play '.mp4' files. I even tried to download .avi file and it is showing file is corrupted. I even tried to change .avi to .mp4 using online tools but nothing worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

Use the python moviepy package

```
from moviepy.editor import *

path="file.avi" 

clip=VideoFileClip(path)
clip.ipython_display(width=280)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert avi to mp4 with ffmepg

```
!ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4
```

Then get the file content into data_url

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode
mp4 = open('output.mp4','rb').read()
data_url = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()
```

Then display it with HTML()

```py
HTML("""
<video controls>
      <source src="%s" type="video/mp4">
</video>
""" % data_url)
```

Here's a [working example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K1rznXf2zrAgbh_qJUV_BsGCYLVOfYJx).

Comment: I am facing an error like this while running on colab " Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg4 (XVID / 0x44495658), none, 1280x720): unspecified pixel format Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options ". While running .avi file in local machine, it is playing without any errors.

Comment: Does not work with this video w/o reencoding https://content.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2017-08/originalContent/170724_15_Setangibeach.mp4